# Parsing text files containing lists of files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have txt files containing info about catalogs and it files on a server. From each file I need only to get 2 catalogs with it filenames to get them into a massive for further comparison with local files.

I thought about line by line reading but I am stuck. Especially if it finds 'SDU__DACS' in filename in other catalog which I'm not interested it writes it to previous catalog name.

I was trying:

```
pathSDU = []
pathSCI = []
filesDict = {}
for file in glob.glob('/foo/bar/catalog/*.txt'):
    with open(os.path.join('/foo/bar/catalog', file), 'r') as openFile:
        print('opening file ' + file)
        for line in openFile:
            if '/ACS/SDU_:' in line:
                pathSDU = line
            else:
                if 'SDU__DACS' in line:
                    if 'manifest' not in line:
                        filesDict.update({line: pathSDU})
            if '/ACS/ScienceDataFile:' in line:
                pathSCI = line
            else:
                if 'SCI__DACS' in line:
                    if 'manifest' not in line:
                        filesDict.update({line: pathSCI})
```

Example of txt files content:

```
/data/foo/bar/ACS/SDU_:
68421952
17660866 2021-09-06 09:56 SDU__DACS_69DC_0241DB01_2021-246T08-13-26__00001.EXM
17660866 2021-09-06 09:41 SDU__DACS_69DB_0241DB01_2021-246T08-12-37__00001.EXM
17660866 2021-09-06 09:24 SDU__DACS_69DA_0241DB01_2021-246T08-11-46__00001.EXM
17660866 2021-09-06 08:27 SDU__DACS_69D9_0241DB01_2021-246T08-10-56__00001.EXM

/data/foo/bar/TGO/ACS/ScienceDataFile:
69881252
 14759936 2021-09-05 21:51 SCI__DACS__0241DA01_2021-246T04-26-15__00001.EXM
       53 2021-09-05 21:51 SCI__DACS__0241DA01_2021-246T04-26-15__00001.EXM.manifest
318758912 2021-09-05 14:42 SCI__DACS__0241D801_2021-246T00-30-32__00001.EXM
```

Comment: you create a dict with the key `/data/foo/bar/ACS/SDU_:` but since you read many files in a loop you override it again and again. Share 2 files as an example and explain how should the final output look like.

Comment: @balderman the opposite, the keys are the filenames and the values are the paths, nothing is being overridden

Comment: @Shinratensei exactly I swapped it to get things right

Comment: @Shinratensei - thanks for the correction. I still need the OP to share more data like I have asked in previous comment.

Comment: What is `/foo/bar/catalog`? How does that relate to the files shown at `/data/foo/bar`? Also, what specific output are you expecting?

Comment: @balderman
output I need is filename: pathname for further ineraction with it. Like one next iterations I cut line to leave just filename.

Comment: Given 2 text files - what should be the expected output? Share them as part of the post please.

Comment: Theres a problem to share them in the post because they are not small. 500 lines in the smallest and about 126 thousand in the biggest one.

Comment: @balderman Example given in the post it is short fragment which each file contains which I am looking for.

Comment: @OneCricketeer `/foo/bar/catalog` is a directory where all txt files which I need to parse located. I excpect to get a massive with `filename: pathname` or `pathname: filename`  of  needed files for further interactions with them as output. Example of files and their pathnames I needed with txt file structure I pasted in the post.

Comment: Dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys, so `filename: pathname` is your only option unless you group all files into a list with the path as a key to the list

Comment: @OneCricketeer Okay. Thanks. The question is how to correctly I should get filenames which located under pathname and dont write filenames from paths that I dont needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following.

```
with open('data.txt') as openFile:

    path = None
    files = []
    filesDict = dict()

    for line in openFile:
        line = line.rstrip()

        # empty line; you're done with one folder  
        # store the previous data, if it exists and start a new collection 
        if not line.strip(): 
            if files and (path is not None):
                filesDict[path] = files
                path = None; files = []
                continue
    
        # paths end with colons, don't store specific variables for each path 
        if line.endswith(':'):  
            # save previous results, if any 
            if files and (path is not None):
               filesDict[path] = files
    
            path = line; files = []
            next(openFile) # skip the line with only a number 
            continue 
    
        if path:  # only continue if path is defined 
            if 'manifest' not in line:
                files.append(line)
    
    # last folder read from file but not yet stored 
    if path:
        filesDict[path] = files
```

### Sample run

```
for p, l in filesDict.items():
  print(p)
  for f in l:
    print('\t', f)
```

Output

```
/data/foo/bar/ACS/SDU_:
     17660866 2021-09-06 09:56 SDU__DACS_69DC_0241DB01_2021-246T08-13-26__00001.EXM
     17660866 2021-09-06 09:41 SDU__DACS_69DB_0241DB01_2021-246T08-12-37__00001.EXM
     17660866 2021-09-06 09:24 SDU__DACS_69DA_0241DB01_2021-246T08-11-46__00001.EXM
     17660866 2021-09-06 08:27 SDU__DACS_69D9_0241DB01_2021-246T08-10-56__00001.EXM
/data/foo/bar/TGO/ACS/ScienceDataFile:
      14759936 2021-09-05 21:51 SCI__DACS__0241DA01_2021-246T04-26-15__00001.EXM
     318758912 2021-09-05 14:42 SCI__DACS__0241D801_2021-246T00-30-32__00001.EXM
```

Comment: you never reset the value of path back to none for the next loop, so it should append all entries containing 'manifest' after the first time path is set.

Comment: And if it's set to none, then `if path` would be skipped and no lines would be added (line is not empty and line doesn't end with a colon)

Comment: Im testing it on 1 file atm. Ive changed `if line.endswith(':'):` to `if line.endswith(':\n'): ` because originally the output was `{None: []}`. When I changed it started to write evrything in value [] even number line. Ive tried  `if line.endswith('/ACS/SDU_:\n'):` also but I only get `{'/data/foo/bar/Science/TGO/ACS/SDU_:\n': ['/data/foo/bar/RELAY/EDM/SDU_:\n', '0\n']}`.

Comment: You might want to use `line = line.rstrip()` immediately after the `for` line

Comment: If i add this immediately after the `for` line output becomes `{None: []}` @OneCricketeer

Comment: I updated my answer after running it with the exact "file content" shown in the question, and that is the output I got. Notice I only use one file, so your issue might exist with your glob loop

Comment: Thanks. Im getting evreything that is in file not only `/data/foo/bar/ACS/SDU_:` and `/data/foo/bar/TGO/ACS/ScienceDataFile:`. :(
File also contain such lines as:

/data/part04_data04/Science/TGO/NOMAD/SDU_:
160648332
17660866 2020-06-02 07:28 SDU__DNMD_3945_032BF801_2020-153T11-22-07__00001.EXM
17660866 2020-06-02 07:26 SDU__DNMD_3944_032BF801_2020-153T11-13-00__00001.EXM

/data/part04_data04/RELAY/EDM/DataProducts/OpenLoop/TM:
0

/data/part04_data04/RELAY/EDM/PassProduct:
0

/data/part04_data04/RELAY/EDM/SDU_:
0
@OneCricketeer

Comment: Ive changed `if line.endswith(':'): ` to `if line.endswith('/ACS/SDU_:') or line.endswith('/ACS/ScienceDataFile:'):` now it works but only for 1 file the issue with glob loop u told happend @OneCricketeer

Comment: for some reason it saves result only from last txt file in folder @OneCricketeer

Comment: Like I said, the problem is with your glob loop. Notice that my `filesDict` is **inside** the `with ... openFile`, not outside some other loop

Comment: If you want to save the result for each glob iteration, then you need to save the result somewhere else before you override `filesDict` variable with an empty dict

Comment: @OneCricketeer I just put `filesDict = dict()` before this part of code and it works fine. Could you suggest how to avoid writing paths with lines under it like `/data/foo/bar/ATB6/TGO/ACS/SDU_:` and `/data/foo/bar/ATB7B/TGO/ACS/ScienceDataFile:` because it corresponds this statement aswell `if line.endswith('/ACS/SDU_:') or line.endswith('/ACS/ScienceDataFile:'):`? Ive tried to make statement like `if ('ATB6' and 'ATB7B') not in line:`

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with just `endswith(':')` as it's working in my answer. And that's not how you check if two values are in a string (you need to use `in` keyword twice; that line evaluates to `if True in line`, which is false because boolean types are not in string types) I suggest you create a new post to clarify what different output you want / different inputs you have since you've already accepted this answer

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hmm. This is weird now `endswith(':')` working fine. Yesterday it worked incorrect. Yep thanks I gonna make one more post to make things clear.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ive checked again and `endswith(':')` is parsing evry directory is in file. Ive created new post aswell.

Comment: @OneCricketeer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104158/exclude-some-lines-by-keywords-while-parsing-txt-file