# Exclude some lines by keywords while parsing txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to parse txt files which contains lists of directories and files in it. Im intrested in `'/ACS/SDU_:'` and `'/ACS/ScienceDataFile:'` directories. How I can exclude such dirs as `/data/foo/bar/ATB6/Science/TGO/ACS:` and `/data/foo/bar/ATB7B/Science/TGO/ACS:`? I was trying to exclude them by `if 'ATB6' not in line:` `if 'ATB7B' not in line:` statements.

```
filesDict = dict()
for file in glob.glob('/foo/bar/catalog/*.txt'):
    with open(os.path.join('/foo/bar/catalog', file), 'r') as openFile:
        path = None
        files = []
        for line in openFile:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if not line.strip():
                if files and (path is not None):
                    filesDict[path] = files
                    path = None
                    files = []
                    continue
            if line.endswith('/ACS/SDU_:') or line.endswith('/ACS/ScienceDataFile:'):
                # save previous results, if any
                if files and (path is not None):
                    filesDict[path] = files
                    path = line[5:-2]
                    files = []
                    next(openFile)
                    continue
    
            if path:
                if 'manifest' not in line:
                    files.append(line)

    # last folder read from file but not yet stored
    if path:
        filesDict[path] = files
```

**Exmaple of txt file content:**

```
/data/foo/bar/Science/TGO/NOMAD/ScienceDataFile:
123992
 3766886 2016-02-17 10:44 SCI__DNMD__03000082_2016-048T09-07-27__00001.EXM
 5245980 2016-02-17 10:00 SCI__DNMD__03000081_2016-048T08-48-13__00001.EXM
 3766570 2016-02-17 09:26 SCI__DNMD__03000080_2016-048T08-20-01__00001.EXM

/data/foo/bar/Science/TGO/CASSIS/SDU_:
208744
26934224 2016-02-17 13:11 SDU__DCAS_0003_01200002_2016-047T15-18-48__00001.EXM
35322818 2016-02-17 13:11 SDU__DCAS_0002_01200002_2016-047T15-03-48__00001.EXM

/data/foo/bar/Science/ACS/SDU_:
68421952
17660866 2021-09-06 09:56 SDU__DACS_69DC_0241DB01_2021-246T08-13-26__00001.EXM
17660866 2021-09-06 09:41 SDU__DACS_69DB_0241DB01_2021-246T08-12-37__00001.EXM
17660866 2021-09-06 09:24 SDU__DACS_69DA_0241DB01_2021-246T08-11-46__00001.EXM
17660866 2021-09-06 08:27 SDU__DACS_69D9_0241DB01_2021-246T08-10-56__00001.EXM

/data/foo/bar/Science/TGO/ACS/ScienceDataFile:
69881252
 14759936 2021-09-05 21:51 SCI__DACS__0241DA01_2021-246T04-26-15__00001.EXM
       53 2021-09-05 21:51 SCI__DACS__0241DA01_2021-246T04-26-15__00001.EXM.manifest
318758912 2021-09-05 14:42 SCI__DACS__0241D801_2021-246T00-30-32__00001.EXM

/data/foo/bar/ATB6/Science/TGO/ACS/ScienceDataFile:
0

/data/foo/bar/ATB7B/Science/TGO/ACS/SDU_:
4
4
 116 2017-07-12 11:59 ScienceDataFile/
4096 2017-07-12 11:56 SDU_/
```

Answer (score 1):

> exclude such dirs as /data/foo/bar/ATB6/Science/TGO/ACS: and /data/foo/bar/ATB7B/Science/TGO/ACS:?

Your `if line.endswith` check will work only on the times you see *that line*. The condition itself is therefore evaluated at the wrong time as you're parsing the file (*before* you see the files for that path you are interested in).

You need to check the `path` instead and store the suffixes you are interested in (use this each time you "save" the `path` in the dict)

```
if any(path.endswith(x) for x in ['/ACS/SDU_:', '/ATB6/Science/TGO/ACS/ScienceDataFile:']):
    filesDict[path] = files
files = []
```

Change the `endswith(':')` back, as this will correctly identify all paths, not only those you are interested in. Feel free to extract the `['ACS/SDU_:', '/ACS/ScienceDataFile:']` list to its own variable for re-use

Comment: Alright now I see why I should leave `endswith(':')`. Sorry man check post pls Ive updated it I have two at least simillar paths in the beginning and in the end the only difference is in `ATB6` and `ATB7B`. How I can exclude them?

Comment: As answered, you can change the strings within the `in` list to capture the ones you want.